# Logic app connect with Api in VPN

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, paas

**My Use Case**

On Email trigger

1) Logic app should dump email content in blob

2) Call Api app(which is inside a VPN(App service enviornment))

1st step is working fine

But in second step i am getting error in HTTP request connector

I suppose it issue of DNS resolution but i dont know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: How do your Logic App resource and app service relate to each other as far as virtual networks in Azure are concerned?  Are they within the same subscription and vnet?

Comment: Logic Apps can invoke API behind VPN. You can use API Management as middleware to talk to such API though.

Comment: @KyleBurns yes they are in same subscription,  but vnet ? can i assign vnet to logic app?

Comment: @DerekLi can you give any example or link for you answer

Comment: @gauravmoolani - I did a little more digging and realized that because Logic App is multi-tenant you can't currently configure advanced networking.  I think that DerekLi is correct about needing to use API Management to make it happen.